# Regex - how to ignore strings starting with underscore

Tags: c#, regex

I need to test this string to match anything not starting with an underscore:

`__$id0 = "foo"`

My approach was to match the string starting with an underscore, then making that match into a negative look-ahead and capturing the rest.

Testing for the underscore works:

`(_.*?\s)` gives one hit: '`__$id0`'

However, making this into a negative look-ahead does not have the desired effect:

`((?!_.*?\s).*?\s)` results in

```
MATCH 1
1.  [2-7]   `$id0 `
MATCH 2
1.  [7-9]   `= `
MATCH 3
1.  [9-16]  `"lala"`
```

The underscores are stripped from the first string, but the string itself still is in the resultset. I want to exclude that first string completely, because it starts with `_`.

**How can I exclude strings starting with `_`?**

The result should be this:

```
MATCH 1
1.  [7-9]   `= `
MATCH 2
1.  [9-16]  `"lala"`
```

(Source: https://www.regex101.com/r/cC2pV7/1)

Comment: just put `^` at first to just matching from start of the string. otherwise it will match from middle of string.

Comment: What do you want the results to look like?

Comment: @saluce added expected result.

Comment: you can try this: [`(?!_)\s+([a-zA-z0-9$"=_]+)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f!_)%5cs%2b(%5ba-zA-z0-9%24%22%3d_%5d%2b)&i=__%24id0+%3d+%22foo%22)

Comment: @Grundy that only works because it's not matching `\s` at the beginning.  Change it to `\s*` and your regex fails.  Make it in the middle of text, like `private string __$id0 = "lala"` and it fails as is.

Comment: Maybe [this regex - `(?<![\w."$])([^_][\w."$]*)\s*=\s*(\S*)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c!%5b%5cw.%22%24%5d)(%5b%5e_%5d%5b%5cw.%22%24%5d*)%5cs*%3d%5cs*(%5cS*)&i=__%24id0+%3d+%22foo%22%0d%0a%24id0+%3d+%22foo%22) suits here? Or [`(?<![\w."$])((?!_)[\w."$]*)\s*=\s*(\S*)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c!%5b%5cw.%22%24%5d)((%3f!_)%5b%5cw.%22%24%5d*)%5cs*%3d%5cs*(%5cS*)&i=__%24id0+%3d+%22foo%22%0d%0aprivate+string+%24id0+%3d+%22lala%22%0d%0a).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the trick...match what you don't want to keep, then match and capture everything else.

```
[\s]?_[^\s]*|\s?(.*?)\s+?
```

On the left side of the `|` pipe, you are matching anything that starts with an underscore.  If it matches, it takes that side of the regex.  Otherwise, attempt to match the right side of the underscore, which is captured and matches anything that doesn't start with an underscore.

This will also allow you to match when an underscore is present in the middle or at the end of a string.

https://www.regex101.com/r/cC2pV7/3

Answer (score 4):

You should first check for the start of a line using `^`. And then, you want to match anything that *isn’t* an underscore, so you use an inverted character class: `[^_]`:

```
^([^_].*?)\s*=\s*(.*?)
```

[Working example](https://www.regex101.com/r/cC2pV7/2)

Comment: 1.) Eventually, I want to use this on a large block of text; I don;t think the start anchor is going to help me, but I'll try \b instead.
2.) I want to capture every singe word separated by spaces, except the one with the underscore. I've tried modding this to do that, but it just falls back to stripping `_`.

Comment: Or you can also check for whitespace in the front (since those variable names are unlikely to have whitespace, right?)

Answer (score 1):

I know the tag and everything appears to say regex must be used, but in case it helps someone, how about:

```
string_to_compare[0] =! '_'
```

Answer (score 0):

By using the following regex:

```
^(?!_).+
```

It matches words or phrases without an underscore at the beginning. if you need only the words use this:

```
^(?!_)\w+
```

Both work for C# and JavaScript.